# Want to rotate out node group in EKS

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I want to replace a node group entirely with fresh nodes in an EKS node group.

Whats is the difference between

```
eksctl scale nodegroup --cluster=$CLUSTER_NAME --nodes=0
```

And draining/deleting nodegroup, then provisioning via Terraform?

Answer (score 1):

To replace an entire node group in an EKS cluster, you can either use the eksctl command or manually drain and delete the node group and provision a new one with Terraform.

```
eksctl scale nodegroup --cluster=my-cluster --nodes=0
```

This command will drain and delete all nodes in the node group, leaving the node group empty. You can then use the eksctl create nodegroup command to provision a new node group with the desired configuration.

> The difference between draining and deleting a node group is that :

- Draining a node group will gracefully terminate the nodes in the
  group, while deleting a node group will immediately terminate the
  nodes.
- Draining a node group is typically used when you want to replace the
  node group with a new one, while deleting a node group is usually
  used when you want to completely remove the node group from the EKS
  cluster

For more information refer to this [EKS Doc](https://eksctl.io/usage/managing-nodegroups/)